# Heating Sand/Ceramic/Refractory Material under vacuum

Tags: metallurgy, metals

In a Vacuum Metallurgy (Casting), a mold needs to be heated (500 to 700 degrees) to reduce thermal shock on the metal surface. Normally, a gas fired oven is employed for such job, but in a vacuum environment how do you achieve the same?

Comment: Couldn't you use a lamp and heat it by radiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, After Some Wandering on Google, I came to know the process,

One Idea is to heat mold by radiation, A ceramic heater could be suitable for it.

But the way it is actually done is,

First preheat the mold in a gas fired oven, and in parallel start vacuum induction furnace to melt the material in different chamber,

once mold and material is ready to be pour, put mold in a vacuum chamber for casting, close the chamber and starts molding.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXFRRg8YMT0

this video gives nice explanation of the process.

Answer (score 2):

A second idea for added control, if needed:

If your molders can accomplish it, you could also bury a [heating coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_element) in the mold before you harden it.  The heating cable would need to be able to withstand the liquid metal temperatures, so something like [tungsten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten) would be required.  This would also allow some control of the process after pouring - if you needed to get to a different [metallurgical state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel#Material_properties), for example.  The heater near the edges would keep the edges hot while the inside cools.